# How to retrive the accidently closed the modifying procedure in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select, stored-procedures

I am altering a Stored Procedure and due to Power fluctation my system has shutdown. Now i need to retrive that procedure. Is there any way to do this thing in SQL Server 2008.

I tried

```
SELECT cp.objtype AS PlanType
    ,OBJECT_NAME(st.objectid,st.dbid) AS ObjectName
    ,cp.refcounts AS ReferenceCounts
    ,cp.usecounts AS UseCounts
    ,st.text AS SQLBatch
    ,qp.query_plan AS QueryPlan
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans AS cp
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(cp.plan_handle) AS qp
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(cp.plan_handle) AS st
```

Comment: Not sure I understand. If you modify a SP that means you actually have a SP to modify so the version of the SP that you started to modify is still around right? And what you are missing is the modifications you were doing to it. And when your system crashed you had not yet applied the modifications using `alter procedure`. Have I understood your situation correctly?  If that is the case I think you are out of luck. BTW, since the new version if the SP has never been in the DB nor executed you can not find it in the procedure cache.

Comment: ok thank you so i dont have another option to retrive the unexecuted code.

Comment: If you used SQL Server Management Studio you might get lucky with `AutoRecover`. Have a look in `My Documents\SQL Server Management Studio\Backup Files\Solution1`

Comment: In that folder it shows only new query results that are auto recover files. i already tried this one previously.

Comment: For the future, stored proc changes are code changes and thus shouldbe source control.  There is no reason why you can save the sql script periodically to your source control location while you are working on it as long as you don't check it in until it is complete (or only check into a local branch). That way if you lose power, you have a partial change saved when making complex changes.  Further, you should have your work computer on a battery backup so that you have time to save things in progress before totally losing power.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you never executed your query it is gone.  The [SSMS Tools Pack](http://ssmstoolspack.com/) provides autosave functionality.  This is also built into SSMS 2012+.

There are no such thing as a *live edit* of a stored procedure (or any other object). Think of SSMS as text editor who can execute your text as command in the server. When you *modify* a stored procedure, SSMS retrieves the definition from the server, and then pre-populates your script. You can then save this script as a text file in your HD, or execute it.

Comment: If i never executed i can get it by executing the above query. I asking is there any chance while altering procedure.

Comment: Any edits you make to the script/proc/etc in ssms, that are not saved (in ssms or elsewhere), are gone if ssms closes unexpectedly.  Unless you are using 2012+ or have some other plug-in to do it.

Answer (score -1):

If you already executed your statement, here the query to find it in sys

```
select * from sys.all_objects where type='P'
```

you can also search by and "modify_date"

If you did not executed it. SSMS will have backup of your SQL file in below location. You need to have auto recovery enabled for this.
C:\Documents and Settings\Your Name Here\My Documents\SQL Server Management Studio\Backup Files

If you do not have auto recover enabled. No way to get it back. But for feature use, check below link to enable auto recovery

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/11/28/sql-server-auto-recovery-file-settings-in-ssms-sql-in-sixty-seconds-034-video/